# server connection difficulty with flask.py file running inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I have a tensorflow serving with flask app running inside a docker container. I gave in flask_client.py file to access from outside the container.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

When i run this flask_client.py file,

```
python flask_client.py --server=172.17.0.2:9000
Initialization done.
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My Container IPAddress : 172.17.0.2 and its running on the port 9000

My VM IPAddress: 192.168.99.100

and flask is running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/

But i when tried to access from http://192.168.99.100:5000/, it showed 
[image]

But I could ping 192.168.99.100 and 172.17.0.2 from command prompt

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 192.168.99.100

Pinging 192.168.99.100 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.99.100: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.99.100: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.99.100: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.99.100: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.99.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 4ms

C:\Windows\system32>ping 172.17.0.2

Pinging 172.17.0.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.17.0.2: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=63
Reply from 172.17.0.2: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=63
Reply from 172.17.0.2: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=63
Reply from 172.17.0.2: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 172.17.0.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 4ms
```

And when i tired to curl inside the docker container it showed something like this

[image: pic]

these are the ports and address inside my docker container :

[image]

What should do i do now?

**PS: my docker ps is showing any ports**

[image]

Comment: What's the command you use to start the container?

Comment: docker start my_container_id

Comment: You should map your container's ports to host.

Comment: I have already mapped my port 9000. But do i need to map 5000 port too? 5000 port is where my flask application is running. My container runs on 9000

Comment: Yes you should.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map the internal port 5000 of your Flask app to your hosts public port. For example here I'm mapping 192.168.99.100:80 to your containers-ip port 5000.

So if you access in your local browser http://192.168.99.100 you see the content of your `container:5000`

```
docker run -d -p 80:5000 your_image
```

More on [Docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) can be found in the documentation.

Comment: But this will create a new container? you can see that my flask application runs on 5000. So how can i run my image on 5000?

Comment: Also be sure to add `EXPOSE` directive to dockerfile https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose